# My function containing a mysql query launched by ajax is not working in wordpress. What am I missing?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am trying to insert rows into a table I've set up based on user's answers. I have made a child theme and a custom template for the page with the form. My issue is that I have no way of knowing what's going wrong where and why the data isn't being inserted. my js onclick function is as follows, and this file is called question_submit.js:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#questionSubmit").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url:  my_ajax_object.ajax_url, 
            data: { 
                'action' : 'dbtest',
                'option': 1, 
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    })
});
```

Here is where I enqueue the script:

```
function my_enqueue() {
      wp_enqueue_script( 'question_submit', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/question_submit.js', array('jquery') );
      wp_localize_script( 'question_submit', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
 }
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
```

And finally here is the function that's binded to the action:

```
function dbtesting(){
    
    global $wpdb;
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    //$option = sanitize_text_field($_POST["option"]);
    
    $tableName = 'user_answers';
    $insert_row = $wpdb->insert( 
                    $tableName, 
                    array( 
                        'user_id' => 2, 
                        'module_id' => 3, 
                        'section_id' => 1, 
                        'question_id' => 2,
                        'option_no' => 1, 
                    )
                );
    // if row inserted in table
    if($insert_row){
        echo json_encode(array('res'=>true, 'message'=>__('New row has been inserted.')));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array('res'=>false, 'message'=>__('Something went wrong. Please try again later.')));
    }
    wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_dbtest', 'dbtesting' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_dbtest', 'dbtesting' );
```

Both of these functions are in my child theme's functions.php file. Right now I am using hard-coded values jsut to test the functionality, later these values will be dependent on the form answers.

When I click the submit button, there is no change in my table but also no php errors. There is no evidence of the ajax query going through on the XHR section of networks in development tools.

Comment: Rather than alerting use the console.log function so you can see JavaScript objects as well. Add a `console.log(my_ajax_object.ajax_url)` in place of your alert prior to sending the ajax so see if that variable is being properly defined. Second add a `complete` callback to your ajax options and add `console.log(arguments)` to see why the ajax call is failing.

Comment: I believe the variable is being defined properly as `console.log(my_ajax_object.ajax_url);` outputs `my-domain/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. `console.log(arguments);` returns `{0: {...}, 1: "error", ...}` but when I expand it it doesn't go into more description about the error

Comment: Not sure how you're using this but you want `$_POST['option']`, the `data` object IS the `$_POST` object, not a parameter within it.

Comment: K, good news, that means there is an error in your `dbtesting` func. See my previous comment. I'm not seeing where `$_POST['data']` would get defined.

Comment: try `console.log(arguments[0])` to see what that object is. Better yet add the JavaScript `debugger;` command to make your browser freeze at that moment so you can investigate what's going on.

Comment: arguments[o] seems to be an object with function definitions such as abort, always, complete, ..., I don't know what exactly i'm looking for.

Comment: I edited the `$date = $_POST['data']` to `$option = $_POST['option']` and am still encountering errors

Comment: Sure, so we need to figure out why it's failing. That's where you basically need to debug. Do you know how to use xDebug and breakpoints?

Comment: There are a number of ways to debug this, we need to figure out debugging techniques you're comfortable with. The first `argument` that comes back in the `complete` callback is an ajax object. So you can try `console.log(arguments[0].getAllResponseHeaders())` and `arguments[0].responseText)` to get the full set of Headers and response from the server. Does that make sense? Or if you can't step debug, you can simplify your `dbtesting` function so that it's so basic it will always succeed. Then keep adding code back in until it breaks. Then you'll know which line of code broke the ajax response.

Comment: If any of those columns in your database don't allow duplicates then you're going to get errors trying to add the exact same data each time.

Comment: Thank you, I am going to take a short break and come back and try these methods.

Comment: Sounds good, and good luck. At this point, my best guess based on your symptoms is your `$wpdb->insert(..)` is throwing an error.